# How to change size of date picker control in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Date picker field is sooooo large it is making my table look like crap. I would think that it would be easy to make the date picker any size. But it eludes me.

Is there a way to control how much space the date picker takes up?

Comment: Are you using the Date Picker Content Control? Going int Design Mode, you can change the placeholder text, which is not that larger than most dates would be, at least long form.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the "place holder" text was far too long to fit in the cell. The place holder text can be edited in design mode. Replacing the placeholder text with a space fixed my issue.